# Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6) localizedStringWithFormat

Tags: ios, localization, swift3, xcode8-beta6

Is there a better way to get a localized format and substitute strings in with Xcode 8 Swift 3?  Do I need to use NSString, and cast back and forth between NSString and String?

```
let localizedDue = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Due: %@", comment: "due date label with date") as NSString, formattedDate) as String
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I may be missing something, but in Swift 3, `String` has a type method `localizedStringWithFormat` and you can write something like this:

```
let localizedDue = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Due: %@", comment: "due date label with date"), formattedDate)
```

If this is not what you are seeking for, please update your post.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I had tried that.  Maybe the code complete tool in Xcode wasn't helping.